# Desktop (chrome) aframe ar failed; camera works but no box or model not sure what to expect

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

The following is the code from the example posed on the aframe blog.  The result shows the camera image only; no box and no model:
not sure what to expect.   The model is there and js libraries are there.
Should I see the box and model somewhere in my camera image?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- include A-Frame obviously -->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
    <!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
    <script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style=’margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;’>
    <a-scene 
        embedded arjs=’sourceType: webcam;’>
        <!-- create your content here. just a box for now -->
        <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 1 scale = "2 2 2" color="red";'
        >
        </a-box>
        <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
        <a-entity camera
        >
        </a-entity>
        <a-marker preset=’hiro’>
        </a-marker>
        <a-collada-model
                id = "titlexx1b"
                src="models/man_default.dae" position = "1 1 1" 
                scale = "1 1 1"
                >
            </a-collada-model>
      </a-scene>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the box and the model to the markers you want to put them on. In this case the hiro marker. Usually, it's not recommended to put more than one object on a single marker.
Another thing is, I'm not sure that DAE files are supported by A-frame / AR.js. Consider using a supported format.